# Why is this slider disappearing after few seconds?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i'm working on this slider located on http://www.eclectogroove.com/new-site

You can see the slider appear at first but after it slides a few times the image will disappear.

I have no idea what is going on. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A quick look and there are multiple JS errors at console. Have a look at those errors.

Answer (score 1):

It's trying to load a bunch of images that don't exist, the console shows:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  http://www.eclectogroove.com/new-site/images/gal-two-col-1.jpg

And additional messages like:

> GET http://www.eclectogroove.com/new-site/undefined 404 (Not Found) jquery.min.js:130

If you leave it long enough, the image(s) that did load are shown again.

Are you using a plugin for the carousel? You'll need to post some code and additional information for a more detailed answer